# RavenDB embedded - when trying to use LoadStartingWithAsync or StreamAsync it doesn't returns expected results

Tags: c#, .net, database, nosql, ravendb

When i'm trying to use embeddable ravenDB in tests and use LoadStartingWithAsync or StreamAsync it doesn't return expected results. When the code is performing not in tests it is working fine.

My configuration of ravendb for tests looks like:

```
        using (var store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
        {
            RunInMemory = true,
            UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true
        })
```

I'm using compound string Id for example:

```
$"employeeReport/{reportId}-{employeeId}"
```

When I use

```
session.LoadAsync<EmployeeReport>(2-12) - for example
```

It works, but when I'm trying to use that ones:

```
var reports = await session
    .Advanced.LoadStartingWithAsync<EmployeeReport>("EmployeeReport/", ReportId + "*", 0, 128);
```

Or

```
var reportsStream = await session.Advanced.StreamAsync<EmployeeReport>($"EmployeeReport/{ReportId}");
```

It returns empty collection.